# update multiple records in mongodb using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have mongodb collection with below documents.

[image]

I wanted to update phone = 9876054321 where Email = xyz@gmail.com in Nodejs mongoose. My results should be like below.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the Model created correctly, just try

```
await Model.updateMany({ Email : "xyz@gmail.com" }, { phone : 9876054321 });
let result = await Model.find({Email  : "xyz@gmail.com"}).lean();
console.log(result)
```